# Why do my objects disappear from certain angles when played in the BGE

Tags: game-engine, objects, 3d-view

I am new to blender and I was wanting to make a FPS game using the BGE.
I have my character and rig setup with the right arm a different object so it can move freely while aiming.
    I set up my camera in front of the seprate arm and when I played the game, the arm disappeared. When i viewed the arm from different angles and played the game, the arm appeared as normal. Does anyone know why this happened? I have some screenshots to help explain the problem.
[image: Normal view played]

[image: First person view played]

The first image is the Normal view.
The second image is Viewed from first person.

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add this, but I already adjusted the clipping on the camera and view port with no change.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload a .blend?

Comment: How do you upload blend files? Sorry I'm new to this website

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1707" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1707/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening.

However, I found that joining the arm mesh to the rest of the character mesh (with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) (and joining the two armatures, also with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) fixed it.

[image]

My first thought is that the BGE's [view frustum culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) was hiding the arm, but if that's the case, I'm not sure why it doesn't also hide the entire character..

Comment: This happens when the original bounding box (frame 1) of the skin mesh is outside the camera's frustum. The bounding box will not be updated (for speed reasons).

Comment: @Monster In the version with the joined armature/character, it works even when the camera's frustum doesn't intersect the character's un-posed bounding box. How come?

Comment: I guess the bounding box is bigger than before. You can see the bounding box by enabling Game/Show Physics Vizualisation. It is the physics box, but it does not change too. (it is not visible when Physics is disabled e.g. set to Ghost))

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem but have realised that it has to do with clipping when it is set too high.

The default is 1000m and that works fine with new Blender projects but, for some unknown reason to me, you will have to lower your clipping distance from 1000m to 500m to see the meshes. 500m works for me but you can change it to whatever works.

This isn't a total fix, but it works for me and should hopefully for you.

King regards,
Mallard